# How to fix git merge conflict wile keeping both versions?

Tags: python, git, merge, conflict

```
    def main():
<<<<<<< HEAD
    print("Start of program>>>>>>>")
=======
    print("End of program!")
>>>>>>> improvement-to-the-code

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

What happens is that there are two versions of what happens in `main()`:

First version `HEAD` branch:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    # Relevant code of `HEAD` branch below [START]
    print("Start of program>>>>>>>")
    # Relevant code of `HEAD` branch above [END]
=======
```

Second Version `improvement-to-the-code` branch:

```
=======
    # Relevant code of `improvement-to-the-code` branch below [START]
    print("End of program!")
    # Relevant code of `improvement-to-the-code` branch above [END]
>>>>>>> improvement-to-the-code
```

To fix the conflict you can write the `improvement-to-the-code` branch dode right after the `HEAD` branch dode:

```
def main():
    print("Start of program>>>>>>>")
    print("End of program!")

main()
```

Comment: @SunilKumarRathore Welcome! Mark as solved & vote up!